# Is backpropagation is used in validation data set?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, validation, backpropagation

Hello guys I am very confused as I am building a deep learning image classifier from raw python code ,so my question is that:-is backpropagation used in validation set to get the model more accuracy in validation set (I have only one model )

Comment: Are you asking if the validation set is also used for training of neural networks?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Back propagation occurs only during training.

During validation, it uses the learnt parameters to predict and evaluate on validation set.